# Access to files in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have an application written in c# using xamarin.forms that needs to access files on the device (read/write). But the problem is that I can't request permission. If I request in any of these ways, nothing happens, and the function returns `Denied`:

```
var set_read = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
```

```
DependencyService.Get<ISettingsService>().OpenSettings(); //similar to the above, only using DependencyService
```

```
var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionAsync<StoragePermission>(); //using a third-party class
```

I also tried to open the settings so that the user could manually enable the permission as follows:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.StartActivity(new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageAllFilesAccessPermission));
```

But this does not work, when accessing any file, an error pops up: there is no access.

Is it possible to open the settings specifically for the current application for reading/writing files? Or maybe there are any other options for requesting permission?

Comment: What path are you trying to access?  Mobile OS do not give the user complete access to the file system.  Each app has its own file sandbox, and access to shared system folders is controlled by the OS.  See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows)

Comment: If you use Android, you could also refer to this : [File Storage and Access with Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/)